# Weighted Lebesgue spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I have seen the norm $N(f)=\sup_{t>0}t^{1/p}f^{**}(t)$ where $f^{**}$ is the maximal function. Which weighted lebesgue space does this norm correspond to?

Comment: It's not a weighted Lebesgue space, but rather a weak Lebesgue space. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space#Decreasing_rearrangements